# How can I install wireless drivers without internet?

Tags: wireless, drivers

[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS]

I have a HP Pavilion dv6 and I need a Broadcom driver (closed source) to access the internet. However, I need to download that, which I am unable to do because I do not have internet access. My ethernet port has always been broken and I have not been able to access the internet since I installed Ubuntu. I need to find a way for me to install those drivers desperately.

I still have Ubuntu on my USB, which for some reason, did have the ability to install that driver (I think it's due to the fact that it already has it somewhere in the files). On my USB Ubuntu, I have that particular driver installed. I was thinking that if one of you knows where drivers are installed, I could locate those files on the USB Ubuntu, then plug in an additional USB to copy them; restart my computer to the harddrive Ubuntu and then install the files from the (additional) USB.

I would really appreciate help since to me a computer without internet is useless.

Comment: Check out the [howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx).

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the driver is in use while you boot from that usb, just issue `lshw`,  find out `network` section, under that find your Broadcom device, go to its `configuration:` section; there you'll find a `driver=xxx` entry, that's the driver module in use. Then issue the command `modinfo xxx` where `xxx` is the driver module name. You'll find the location of the module under `filename:` entry. It should be a `.ko`(kernel object) file.
By the way, make sure the USB installation and the HDD installation uses same kernel version or copying won't work.

Comment: I will definately give this a try, I'll tell you if it worked :)